# Python Google My Business V1 Error - AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'locations'

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-my-business-api

I am trying to get the listings under a Local Account in Google My Business through API.

```
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secret.json"
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage"]

API_SERVICE_NAME = "mybusiness"
API_VERSION = "v1"

service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        API_SERVICE_NAME,
        API_VERSION,
        credentials=credentials,
        discoveryServiceUrl="https://mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1",
    )

response = (
    service.accounts()
    .locations()
    .lists(parent="accounts/113097808549740046769")
    .execute()
)
```

This is returning error: `AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'locations'`

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [accounts.locations.list method](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/accounts.locations/list) is part of the Business Information API, not the Account Management API.